# JSON Error - Invalid type in JSON write (Posm)

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I have one array on entity class (with Posm name). So i need to send that entity data to server through php url using NSJSONSerialization. But here after dataWithJSONObject, it is crashing with given error...

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:     
  'Invalid type in JSON write (Posm)'
```

here is my code what i did..

```
    NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    array1= [Util getPosmArrayPreference:@"NbPosm"];  //this array1 have Posm entity data, that i need to send using POST http method.

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionnary setObject:array1 forKey:@"First"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];

    NSString *urlString =@"http://..........checklist_api.php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

Posm.h class :-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Posm : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *posmId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *posmName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *posmQuantity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *posmRemarks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *posmAfterImageId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *posmBeforeImageId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *posmAfterData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *posmBeforeData;

@end
```

Posm.m :-

```
#import "Posm.h"

@implementation Posm

@synthesize posmId, posmName, posmQuantity, posmRemarks, posmAfterData, posmBeforeData, posmAfterImageId, posmBeforeImageId;

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [[Posm alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.posmId = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmId"];
        self.posmName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmName"];
        self.posmQuantity = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmQuantity"];
        self.posmRemarks = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmRemarks"];

        self.posmAfterImageId = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmAfterImageId"];
        self.posmBeforeImageId = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmBeforeImageId"];

        self.posmAfterData=[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmAfterData"];
        self.posmBeforeData=[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"posmBeforeData"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:posmId forKey:@"posmId"];
    [coder encodeObject:posmName forKey:@"posmName"];
    [coder encodeObject:posmQuantity forKey:@"posmQuantity"];
    [coder encodeObject:posmRemarks forKey:@"posmRemarks"];

    [coder encodeObject:posmAfterImageId forKey:@"posmAfterImageId"];
    [coder encodeObject:posmBeforeImageId forKey:@"posmBeforeImageId"];

    [coder encodeObject:posmAfterData forKey:@"posmAfterData"];
    [coder encodeObject:posmBeforeData forKey:@"posmBeforeData"];
}

@end


+(NSMutableArray *)getPosmArrayPreference:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject1 = [defaults objectForKey:string];
    NSMutableArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arr=(NSMutableArray *) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject1];
    for (int i=0;i<arr.count;i++) {
        NSString *st=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [arr1 addObject:[Util getPosmPreference:st]];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Am I creating the JSON object wrong? Please suggest me that how can i make the entity class (Posm) JSON serialization compatible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code of the method ` [Util getPosmArrayPreference:(NSstring*)str];` ?

Comment: I am getting value of my array1.

Comment: Your array contains which kind of object?

Comment: i am showing you in console..(lldb) po array1
$0 = 0x1e19d540 <__NSArrayM 0x1e19d540>(
<Posm: 0x1d5917c0>,<Posm: 0x1e1b8440>,<Posm: 0x1d5913c0>,<Posm: 0x1e1b5a30>
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are adding POSM object into the array and trying to serialise.Convert your POSM object values into dictionary and add the dictionary into array.

**Edit find the below updated code**

```
NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
array1= [Util getPosmArrayPreference:@"NbPosm"];  
NSMutableArray *posmJSONArray=[NSMutableArray array];
for (Posm *posm in array1) {
    NSMutableDictionary *posmJSON=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [posmJSON setValue:posm.posmId forKey:@"posmId"];
    [posmJSON setValue:posm.posmName forKey:@"posmName"];
    [posmJSONArray addObject:posmJSON];
}    
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionnary setObject:posmJSONArray forKey:@"First"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];

    NSString *urlString =@"http://ebiz.pmgasia.com.sg/iweb/Rms/Mobile/Api/checklist_api.php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

Comment: @kaar3kI am already converting it into dictionary using [dictionnary setObject:array1 forKey:@"First"];

Comment: but the key @"First", i am not using anywhere else in app. is it correct?

Comment: @kaar3kHere i have used ur code.. but it is crashing on same place with below error   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)

Comment: Did u change the lines `NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionnary setObject:posmJSONArray forKey:@"First"];`

Comment: Join the chat session http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/42188/nsjsonserialization